# How to automatically find corrupted PDF files?

Tags: pdf, preview, dropbox

Due to a recent syncing issue with Dropbox I ended with a lot of conflicting copies and corrupted files across different machines. Especially PDF documents seemed to be corrupted in some way that Preview (and other PDF readers) refuses to open them (error *"file empty"*).

I’m not to worried about the data itself, as I have individual backups of those files around and could still restore them directly from Dropbox.

However, since I have almost 10,000 PDFs in my Dropbox, I’m looking for an automated method to at least identify them.

Any idea (software, script etc.) on how to get a list of the faulty ones?